# Android- detecting when user is using the text field

Tags: android, textbox

Is it possible to know if the user is currently using or has clicked on a text field?

I have three text fields and when the user clicks on one text field, I would like for it to become the top priority.

Comment: Yes it is possible...What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to use `View.onFocusChangeListener()`. This callback's first parameter is the `View` that has triggered it, and the second is a `boolean` that determines whether it has been focused or unfocused.

You might find more help [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnFocusChangeListener.html).

```
yourTextField.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    // Do whatever you need
    ...
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible with `addTextChangedListener` of `EditText` like this ;

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

});
```

or get like this also :

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add a click-listner

for example:

```
myTextfield.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
```